# C++ struct pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, struct

my code is not working. I have an error of -fpermissive ("**invalid conversion from 'int' to 'persona*' [-fpermessive]**").
Can you help me? This is my first real program, sorry for the errors and the bad english.

```
    #include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct persona
{
    char nome[20];
    unsigned int eta;
    unsigned int altezza;
    unsigned int peso;
};

int totale = 0;
struct persona prs[100];

void leggere_dati(persona* prs)
{
    cout << "Persona numero: " << (totale + 1) << endl;
    cout << "Nome: " << prs->nome << endl;
    cout << "Eta': " << prs->eta << endl;
    cout << "Altezza: " << prs->altezza << endl;
    cout << "Peso: " << prs->peso << endl;
    cout << "-----------------------------------------------\n";
}

void inserire_dati(persona* prs)
{
    cout << "Nome? ";
    cin >> prs -> nome;
    cout << "\nEta'? ";
    cin >> prs -> eta;
    cout << "\nAltezza? ";
    cin >> prs -> altezza;
    cout << "\nPeso? ";
    cin >> prs -> peso;
}

int main()
{
     int risposte = 0;
    char risp = 0;

        do{
        inserire_dati(totale);
        cout << "Inserire un'altra persona? (S/N)" << endl;
        cin >> risp;
        if (risp == 'S')
    {
        risposte += 1;
        totale++;
        continue;
    }
    } while (risp == 's' || risp == 'S');

    if (risp == 'n' || risp == 'N')
    {
        for (totale = 0; totale <=  risposte; totale++)
            leggere_dati(totale);
    }
}
```

Comment: The variable `totale`, what type is it? Why do attempt to pass it as an argument to the function `inserire_dati`? Are you trying to pass e.g. `&prs[totale]`?

Comment: You should tell readers _where_ that error occurs, i.e. by including the full error text, which should include the line number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling:

```
 inserire_dati(totale);
```

Defined as:

```
void inserire_dati(persona* prs);
```

While totale is:

```
int totale = 0;
```

That is the obvious error. But the background problem is that you don't have an object of the **persona** structure to read the data in. As I understand your code, that line should be:

```
inserire_dati(&prs[totale]);
```

You are accepting a pointer to the **persona** structure in that function, which is correct, since you are going to modify the structure's contents. *totale* holds the last position occupied (I think, but you should increment *totale* unconditionally). In order to get a pointer to the structure you use &, preceded with the object, which is prs[totale]. Since the name of the vector is a pointer to its beginning, `prs + totale` is also acceptable. In that case, you would be using pointer arithmetic, which is less readable.

Also, I don't understand the last part of `main()`.

Finally, if you are really using `C++`, there is no real reason to use `char[]` instead of **string**.

The complete `main()` becomes:

```
int main()
{
    char risp = 0;

    do {
        inserire_dati(&prs[totale]);
        ++totale;
        cout << "Inserire un'altra persona? (S/N)" << endl;
        cin >> risp;
    } while (risp == 's' || risp == 'S');

    for(int i = 0; i < totale; ++i) {
         leggere_dati(&prs[totale]);
    }
}
```

But, well, getting further, I see you are using *totale* as a global variable. I'd wrap *totale* and *prs* in a whole structure.

```
struct personas {
    static const int Max = 100;
    struct prs[Max];
    int totale;
};
```

And a few other [changes which you can find in IDEOne](http://ideone.com/IlLcml).

Hope this helps.

Comment: worth noting is to use appropriate containers like std::vector and std::string.

Comment: @TheTechel Sometimes you just don't need to have dynamic memory, like vectors. (Therefor, I agree that std::string would be a great improvement in this code). If you only need 100 persons, that array is just ok.

Comment: @Shirkam But if you often have fewer than 100, allocating more is wasteful. How many real programs need only fixed numbers of objects? And even if they have a max, how many waste space by allocating a fixed length? The pattern seems like one taught by tutorials to beginners, as if they need another thing with little use in the real world. IME the useful cases for fixed-length arrays are for buffers to compose strings for C, interface with hardware, etc. And those cases are fairly rare. For arbitrary objects this seems hardly useful at all. Learning about `std::vector` would be much more useful